# Why is JVM (JDK 1.6) not using survivor spaces and triggers FGC instead

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm

I'm having this recurring problem with my app servers -- at some point, the JVM stops using survivor spaces, and increases the amount of FGC.

JVM options are: `-XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:ParallelGCThreads=4 -XX:PermSize=256m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -XX:MaxNewSize=1700m -XX:NewSize=1700m -XX:NewRatio=2 -XX:SurvivorRatio=4 -XX:+UseParallelGC -Xms2500m -Xmx2500m -server` (32-bit mode)

I'm seeing this without jstat -gc output (1sec interval)

Working normally: Ran out of Eden, YGC triggered, survived moved over to S0.

```
S0C      S1C      S0U       S1U     EC        EU          OC         OU        PC       PU       YGC    YGCT      FGC   FGCT      GCT
290112.0 290112.0 105412.4 0.0      1160576.0 1084253.6   819200.0   796831.2  262144.0 106050.3 179203 66406.885 20428 31661.316 98068.201
290112.0 290112.0 105412.4 1173.7   1160576.0 1160575.6   819200.0   797324.0  262144.0 106050.3 179204 66406.885 20428 31661.316 98068.201
290112.0 290112.0  0.0     208205.7 1160576.0 86186.5     819200.0   798858.0  262144.0 106050.3 179204 66407.281 20428 31661.316 98068.596
```

Working abnormally: Ran out of Eden, trigger FGC

```
S0C      S1C       S0U    S1U   EC        EU         OC         OU        PC       PU       YGC    YGCT      FGC   FGCT      GCT
290112.0 290112.0  0.0    0.0   1160576.0 927072.3   819200.0   765967.3  262144.0 106206.4 158462 63362.970 26039 40083.545 103446.515
290112.0 290112.0  0.0    0.0   1160576.0 993774.1   819200.0   765967.3  262144.0 106206.4 158462 63362.970 26039 40083.545 103446.515
290112.0 290112.0  0.0    0.0   1160576.0 1160576.0  819200.0   765967.3  262144.0 106206.4 158462 63362.970 26040 40083.545 103446.515
290112.0 290112.0  0.0    0.0   1160576.0 1160576.0  819200.0   765967.3  262144.0 106206.4 158462 63362.970 26040 40083.545 103446.515
290112.0 290112.0  0.0    0.0   1160576.0 133591.1   819200.0   767707.1  262144.0 106206.4 158462 63362.970 26040 40085.194 103448.164
```

And this is at the same step, but with -gccause:

```
S0     S1    E      O      P     YGC     YGCT     FGC   FGCT      GCT        LGCC                 GCC                 
0.00   0.00  83.01  97.22  40.51 158514 63384.780 26045 40092.461 103477.241 unknown GCCause      No GC               
0.00   0.00 100.00  97.22  40.51 158514 63384.780 26046 40092.461 103477.241 Allocation Failure   unknown GCCause     
0.00   0.00 100.00  97.22  40.51 158514 63384.780 26046 40092.461 103477.241 Allocation Failure   unknown GCCause
```

(for "working normally" case, the GC cause listed is the same, "Allocation failure")

Another "interesting" fact about this as the VM that's stuck in doing FGC all the time can actually recover back to normal behavior without any intervention (but it's a bad idea to wait until it does, since 2-3 sec FGC on a frequent basis is a response time killer).

Both processes are running for about the same amount of time (~27 days), have the same heap configuration. Any clues, or just where to dig, would be appreciated.

Versions:

```
$ /home/mispot/jdk1.6.0_45/bin/java -version
java version "1.6.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_45-b06)
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 20.45-b01, mixed mode)
$ uname -a
Linux ip-10-16-30-13 3.14.26-24.46.amzn1.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Dec 10 10:02:43 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

P.S. Yes, there is a plan to move on to JDK 1.8, but upgrade like this takes time, and I was wondering if there is a low hanging fruit here that is worth pursuing.

Comment: Thanks for the downvote. Tbh, if your problem is: "My head hurts if I hit it against this wall." don't be surprised if the advice is: "Stop hitting it against the wall, then". If you are on JDK 6 you are sitting on a ticking timebomb that *will* blow up at some point in the future. Make that fact management's problem, or they will make it yours.

Comment: @kittylyst I didn't downvote your answer

Comment: it would help if you can add the column headers as well like S0C S0U and others :)

Comment: @Arkantos there you go :)

Answer (score 1):

This is merely an analysis and I doubt that it will solve your issue but this will give you some insight :)

I suggest few changes in your VM flags

```
-XX:NewSize=1700m -XX:NewRatio=2 -XX:+UseParallelGC
```

NewSize and NewRatio in your case are contradicting each other, because `NewRatio` is 2, old gen will be 2/3 of heap, new gen will be 1/3 of heap. As the heap size is 2500m, you new gen will be ~833m but you use `NewSize` flag as well, so this will override NewRatio and as you can see in jstat output, new gen is `290112k + 290112k + 1160576k ~= 1740800k`.

- remove `NewRatio` as it's not useful in this case
- Use `-XX:+UseParallelOldGC` in addition to UseParallelGC as the later one only does young gen collection in parallel using 4 threads you configured, old gen is still serial

Use the following flags to get more info about GC

```
-XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps 
-XX:+PrintHeapAtGC -XX:+PrintTenuringDistribution
-Xloggc:logs-dir-path/gc.log
```

Coming to your question, Young GC will occur when Eden is full and any live objects after GC are moved to Survivor spaces(S0 & S1). Usually they hold objects for few GCs before they tenure to Old Generation but **if the Object that they're trying to retain in S0/S1 is bigger than the size of those spaces, then objects are directly moved in to Old generation**. So survivor spaces are not used, eventually old gen will fill up and a Full GC will occur which uses only 1 thread because of just `UseParallelGC`

Also you've set NewSize explicitly to 1700m, so old size will be remaining 800m.
If you've too many long-living objects, then Full GCs will be frequent because of smaller old gen but if your application just creates lots of short living objects, then this is valid, so check on that once.

My Suggestion is to

- Take heap dumps and analyze the object sizes and see if you can
  tune them
- Try adjusting new gen and old gen sizes based on your application
  allocation rates
- As you're on bit 32-bit system, you cannot increase the heap further. So better to move on to bigger systems with 64-bit OS so that you can increase the
  heap, upgrade to latest version of Java7/8 to make use of better collectors

Comment: The memory usage pattern is exactly that - a lot of short lived objects, and some long living objects (~800k seems to be optimal). If my problem is that something happens and Eden leftovers are too big for Survivor space. How performance impacting is gc output? I can only reproduce this on live systems, and only after a long time, and for a short period of it too.

Comment: If you have access, You can turn on the gc logs in live systems as well it has very little overhead

Answer (score -2):

Java 6 is now completely unsupported - it dates from 2006 and has been EOL for several years. The advice is simple: upgrade your Java version and try to repro the problem.

You're also using conflicting GC options and pinning Xms to Xmx - which is not advised on a modern JVM that doesn't need to do capacity planning.

Upgrade to Java 7 (or ideally 8), remove all your GC options except Xmx, add GC logging (including PrintGCDetails and PrintTenuringDistribution) and try to reproduce the issue. Then look in the gc log and see what it says about tenuring.